# How to show that there exists an order $p$ normal subgroup if $|G|=4p$ with $p\geq 5$ prime.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group of order $4p$ with $p\geq 5$ prime. Then there exists a normal subgroup $H\leq G$ of order $p$.

I have proven that $G$ has four one-dimensional irreducible representations. The kernel of each representation is a normal subgroup, but I don't see how can I conclude that this normal subgroup has order $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if you have proved that $|G:G'|=4$, then $|G'|=p$. Now let $H \leq G$ with $|H|=p$. If $H \cap G'=1$ then $|HG'|=|H|\cdot|G'|=p^2 \leq |G|=4p$, whence $p \leq 4$, a contradiction. It follows that $H=G'$, and $H$ is normal.

Comment: I think I see it already, it is not that difficult actually. I agree that $|G'|=p$, and since the commutator subgroup is normal a subgroup, that one does the trick, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes but you need to prove that $H$ is normal. This is avoiding Sylow as you see, just a simple counting argument. This leads to $H \cap G’= G’$, using Lagrange. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 3):

This is an immediate consequence of Sylow's Theorem.  $G$ has a $p$-Sylow subgroup $H$ of order $p$.  Because $H$ is a Sylow subgroup, all other $p$-Sylow subgroups are necessarily conjugate to $H$, and the number $n$ of such conjugates satisfies $n \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.  Since $n \vert \vert G \vert$ and $p \geq 5$, this forces $n=1$ so the unique $p$-Sylow subgroup $H \leq G$ is normal.